# Can we safely put `tomcat.addTldSkipPatterns("*.jar")` for a pure back-end spring boot service using embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Tomcat looks for `*.tld` files during startup within the entire class-path. For a production application, the classpath can be huge and this ends up consuming 10s during startup. I already know that tomcat logs the path that it tried searching for and could not find the TLDs, however, I came across this in the TLD docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnamu.html):

> If you want to redistribute your tag files or implement your custom tags with tag handlers written in Java, you must declare the tags in a tag library descriptor (TLD). A tag library descriptor is an XML document that contains information about a library as a whole and about each tag contained in the library. TLDs are used by a web container to validate the tags and by JSP page development tools.

The service in contention is a pure backend-service and there are no JSP pages being served and no tag files being used and all the spring configuration is Java based. Would then it be fine to just add this option in `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`:

```
tomcat.addTldSkipPatterns("*.jar")
```

(or similar config in `application.properties`)

Comment: I highly doubt it is taking 10s of seconds. Classpath scanning is generally very fast (in the ms range that is, even with a large classpath). So first you should really measure if it takes that long or if something else is taking that long. That being said, you should be able to disable the tld scanning, without any effect on the functioniing of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no JSPs anywhere in your application, setting `TLSjavasToSkip=*.jar` is safe.

Note that classpath-scanning happens for a bunch of other reasons, too, so I tend to agree with @M.Deinum's comment that you probably won't see much of an improvement just by disabling TLD scanning.

Comment: thanks christopher and deinum for your response. I do get your point that classpath-scanning might still be happening due to other reasons, but after changing this config I did see some improvement in bootup of about 6 seconds.